# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\int\limits_0^1 f(x)e^{-nx}\mathrm dx$ where $\,f$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\int\limits_0^1 f(x)e^{-nx}\mathrm dx$ where $\,f$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$.

My problem is that I think there's missing information  about $f$, e.g. some kind of continuity on $0$. Because if we change the variable of integration for $\frac xn$ the integral is equal to
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^n f\left(\frac xn\right)e^{-x}\mathrm dx$$
And that can be dominated by $Me^{-x}$, where $|f|\leq M$. But the convergence is to a function non continue (necessary).

Am I wrong?

Comment: You are absoutely right; the answer should be $lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$.  If the limit does not exist, neither does this integral.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that if $\lvert f(x)\rvert\le M$, then
$$
\left|\,n\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-nx}\,dx\,\right|\le Mn\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^{-nx}\,dx=
-nM \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-nx}}{n}\Big|_0^1=M-M\mathrm{e}^{-n}\to M.
$$
In fact if $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-nx}\,dx=f(0).
$$

Comment: I already notice that, but with the first result we just can assure that the integral is finite, but not find the value.
That's why I think it's necessary the continuity in 0